# Consistent Id of XML output of SQL executed on Data Access Point

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-dap

I run an application on Exact Oline for eco taxes, using XML output with XSL transformation to generate the HTML forms.

A query like:

```
select * from me
```

generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<InvantiveDAPOutput xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!--ecotaksen.be Invantive Data Access Point (Unofficial)-->
  <!--License 'L740757780' registered to Control INFO B.V..-->
  <ResultSets>
    <ResultSet Id="0">
      <Fields>
        <Field>
          <Id>0</Id>
          <Name>CurrentDivision</Name>
          <DatabaseDataType>int32</DatabaseDataTyp...
```

In my XSL I then use for instance:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//InvantiveDAPOutput/ResultSets/ResultSet[@Id='4']/Rows/Row/entity_name_singular" />
```

But when I insert a query somewhere in the process, the Id all change. 1 remains 1 for instance, but the numbers after the new inserted query increase by 1.

Is there a smarter way to make the XSL independent of the number of queries and their order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the desired name of the result set to your query as a hint:

```
select /*+ result_set_name('myname') */ * from me
```

The XML will become like:

```
<ResultSet Id="0" Name="myname">
```

You can find the full syntax for execution hints in [the documentation](http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-sql/grammar#executionHints). This holds for Exact Online as well as other platforms such as Teamleader or salesforce.